# unix script - problem in making a text file

Tags: unix, cygwin

I am writing a simple unix script as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir tmp/temp1
cd tmp/temp1
echo "ab bc cj nn mm" > output.txt
grep 'ab' output.txt > newoutput.txt
```

I got following error message:

```
grep : No such file or directory found output.txt
```

but when I looked into the directory the text is created output.txt...but the type of the file was TXT....I am not sure what it is any help??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have a stray `'\r'` (carriage return) on the line with the `echo` command.  You're creating a file called `"output.txt\r"`, and then trying to read a file called `"output.txt"` without the carriage return.

Fix the script so it uses Unix-style line endings (`\n` rather than `\r\n`).  You can use the `unix2dos` command for this.  (Note that `unix2dos`, unlike most filters, overwrites its input file.)